# What do the dimensions describing the crimping tools mean?

Tags: connector, tools, crimp

The crimping tools usually describe an dimension interval they are capable of working with. For example: `0.5 to 6 mm² or 0,1 - 2,5 mm²`.

However when dealing with electronics connectors, the dimension that comes my is `2.54mm`.

From reading forums I got the impression that `0,1 - 2,5 mm²` would work for my `2.45mm` connectors but `0.5 to 6 mm²` wouldn't. At the moment I can't reason why this is like that.

What does the surface the crimping tool are marketed by represent and how does that relate to the `2.54`?

Comment: A link to the datasheet of the crimping tool, or a photo of the tool would help a lot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When expressed in **mm²**, it gives the wire section. Basically, this corresponds to the AWG of the wire. There is a table with corresponding values [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes).

If it was given in **mm**, it would represent the crimping die width (see image):
[image]

At no point the pitch (2.54mm) is relevant when crimping wires. You select the crimping tool depending on the wire size, not the connector pitch.

Comment: Do you have an image showing on what 2.54mm means? I can't visualize what's a `connector pinch`.

Comment: pi**t**ch, not pinch. The pitch is simply the distance between two pins of the connector. A widely used value is 2.54mm (=0.1 inch), but there are many others. An image isn't really necessary to visualize this, is it?